# focusout from a table td not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Focusout from a td which has 4 inputs is not working.
I need to do something when the column losses focus to next column. 
I have tried the following

```
 $(".lineitemdetailsection").on('focusout', function () {
     somecode.......
     alert("");
 });
```

but when I tab focus goes to inputs which is in the same column.

Comment: Show your html please...

Comment: can you share the html and also explain more about the scenario..

Comment: make this in a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j98ayskv/1/

Comment: because the `focusout` is triggered by the `input` element which will get bubbled to the `td` parent.... the [fousout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout) is not the same as [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)